# How to read MTP device storage files?

Tags: java, android

I have an SLR connected to an Android device. How can I read all the pictures from the SLR camera?

I found the SLR camera directory corresponding URI:

```
content://com.android.mtp.documents/document.
```

However, an exception occurred when calling `contentResolver.query()`.

The exception is as follows:

> No persistable permission grants found for UID 10228 and Uri 0 @ content://com.android.mtp.documents/document.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: have you add runtime permissions?

Comment: Yes,i have.<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>

Comment: in which android version you test your project?  is it >=Marshmallow? then you add runtime permissions https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: It's Android N.I have done the requested permission operation.called this method ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission();

Comment: `found the SLR camera directory corresponding URI:`. Please tell how you did that.

Comment: One of the photos I found was content://com.android.mtp.documents/document/102

Comment: ???? Is that an answer to my question? Dont think so. Please tell how you obtained the uri of the photo. And then how that of the camera.

Comment: Intent intent;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, false);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        }
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, false);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

Comment: I get the uri from onActivityResult().

Comment: MANAGE_DOCUMENTS permission is only granted to system apps.